# Pandas fillna() based on specific column attribute

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, nan, mean

Let's say I have this table

```
Type | Killed | Survived
Dog      5         2
Dog      3         4
Cat      1         7
Dog     nan        3
cow     nan        2
```

One of the value on `Killed` is missing for `[Type] = Dog`.

I want to impute the mean in `[Killed]` for `[Type] = Dog`.

My code is as follow:

1. Search for the mean

`df[df['Type'] == 'Dog'].mean().round()`

This will give me the mean (around 2.25)

2. Impute the mean (This is where the problem begins)

`df.loc[(df['Type'] == 'Dog') & (df['Killed'])].fillna(2.25, inplace = True)`

The code runs, but the value is not impute, the NaN value is still there.

My Question is, how do I impute the mean in `[Killed]` based on `[Type] = Dog`.

Comment: How do you get the mean as `2.25`?

Comment: @shivsn I can't figure that out either.

Comment: I'm assuming it's merely a typo or OP is giving the mean from own data distinct from data given in the question.

Comment: @piRSquared When I tried I got confused then figured it out he is taking considering the nan value too `8/3`.

Comment: @shivsn that's what I thought might be the case as well.  So, are you guessing OP meant 2.66 ~= 2.25?

Comment: @piRSquared yeah correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For me working:

```
df.ix[df['Type'] == 'Dog', 'Killed'] = df.ix[df['Type'] == 'Dog', 'Killed'].fillna(2.25)
print (df)
  Type  Killed  Survived
0  Dog    5.00         2
1  Dog    3.00         4
2  Cat    1.00         7
3  Dog    2.25         3
4  cow     NaN         2
```

If need [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) by `Series` - because 2 columns `Killed` and `Survived`:

```
m = df[df['Type'] == 'Dog'].mean().round()
print (m)
Killed      4.0
Survived    3.0
dtype: float64

df.ix[df['Type'] == 'Dog'] = df.ix[df['Type'] == 'Dog'].fillna(m)
print (df)
  Type  Killed  Survived
0  Dog     5.0         2
1  Dog     3.0         4
2  Cat     1.0         7
3  Dog     4.0         3
4  cow     NaN         2
```

If need fillna only in column `Killed`:

```
#if dont need rounding, omit it
m = round(df.ix[df['Type'] == 'Dog', 'Killed'].mean())
print (m)
4

df.ix[df['Type'] == 'Dog', 'Killed'] = df.ix[df['Type'] == 'Dog', 'Killed'].fillna(m)
print (df)
  Type  Killed  Survived
0  Dog     5.0         2
1  Dog     3.0         8
2  Cat     1.0         7
3  Dog     4.0         3
4  cow     NaN         2
```

You can reuse code like:

```
filtered = df.ix[df['Type'] == 'Dog', 'Killed']
print (filtered)
0    5.0
1    3.0
3    NaN
Name: Killed, dtype: float64

df.ix[df['Type'] == 'Dog', 'Killed'] = filtered.fillna(filtered.mean())
print (df)
  Type  Killed  Survived
0  Dog     5.0         2
1  Dog     3.0         8
2  Cat     1.0         7
3  Dog     4.0         3
4  cow     NaN         2
```

Comment: Glad can help you. Nice day!

Answer (score 3):

`groupby` with `transform`

```
df.groupby('Type').Killed.transform(lambda x: x.fillna(x.mean()))
```

#### Setup

```
df = pd.DataFrame([
        ['Dog', 5, 2],
        ['Dog', 3, 4],
        ['Cat', 1, 7],
        ['Dog', np.nan, 3],
        ['Cow', np.nan, 2]
    ], columns=['Type', 'Killed', 'Survived'])

df.Killed = df.groupby('Type').Killed.transform(lambda x: x.fillna(x.mean()))
df
```

[image]

If you meant to consider the `np.nan` when calculating the mean

```
df.Killed = df.groupby('Type').Killed.transform(lambda x: x.fillna(x.fillna(0).mean()))
df
```

[image]

Comment: Wow, I had never heard of `transform`... egads! It's not documented!? What [madness](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) is this?

Answer (score 1):

Two problems: Note that `df.loc[(df['Type'] == 'Dog') & (df['Killed'])]` isn't doing what (I presume) you think it is doing. Instead of selecting rows where type is dog and the column 'Killed', you are selecting rows of type dog, then doing elementwise "and" with the column 'Killed', which will give you garbage - `False` precisely where the columns 'Killed' is `nan`!

See:

```
In [6]: df.loc[(df['Type'] == 'Dog') & (df['Killed'])]
Out[6]: 
  Type  Killed  Survived
0  Dog     5.0         2
1  Dog     3.0         4
```

What you want is the following:

```
In [5]: df.loc[(df['Type'] == 'Dog'), ['Killed']]
Out[5]: 
   Killed
0     5.0
1     3.0
3     NaN
```

One more problem is that you need to use assignment in combination with `.loc`. and `.fillna`, so like the following:

```
In [6]: df.loc[(df['Type'] == 'Dog'), ['Killed']] = df.loc[(df['Type'] == 'Dog'), ['Killed']].fillna(2.25)

In [7]: df
Out[7]: 
  Type  Killed  Survived
0  Dog    5.00         2
1  Dog    3.00         4
2  Cat    1.00         7
3  Dog    2.25         3
4  cow     NaN         2
```

### NOTE

The value you gave for your mean is wrong or does not correspond to the data you gave in the answer. The mean should be 4.