# Filling NaN with data based on condition

Tags: python, pandas

My code looks like that:

```
if df['FLAG'] == 1:
    df['VAL'] = df['VAL'].fillna(median)
elif df['FLAG'] == 0:
    df['VAL'] = df['VAL'].fillna(0)
```

Which returns - The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

I have tried with doing like a mask and then applying it with a.all() but it didn't worked out. I'd be very thankful for enlightment!

Edit: I've solution for my problem right here - [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39242615/pandas-fillna-based-on-specific-column-attribute)

Answer (score 4):

This is an elementwise operation, and you can vectorize this. Build an array with `np.where` and pass that to `fillna`.

```
df['VAL'] = df['VAL'].fillna(np.where(df['FLAG'], median, 0))
```

Comment: Hm, strage because I get the type error where value parameter must be a scala, dict or Series, but you passed a ndarray

Answer (score 1):

You may can do this

```
 df.loc[df['VAL'].isna(),'Val']=df['FLAG']*median
```